# How to remove namespace prefix in Node.js

Tags: xml, node.js, web-services, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I am consuming a Web service in *Node.js*.

In the SOAP response, the elements come with a namespace prefix, like

```
<common_v26_0:BookingTravelerRef Key="lGZGs8IORfCNhaHEyHf0FA=="/>
```

How do remove these prefixes (such as `common_v26_0:`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually should not have to *remove* any prefixes. If your intention is to read data from the XML you can use *namespace-aware* methods from the DOM API or *register* a namespace if you are using XPath. In XPath you can also select data *ignoring* the namespace.

You have to discover what the namespace is. For example, in your SOAP response there should be an atrribute with a namespace declaration like `xmlns:common_v26_0="your-namespace-uri"`. You will need that *your-namespace-uri* to select data from your response:

```
var nsURI = "your-namespace-uri"; // replace with the actual namespace for `common_v26_0`
```

To select the `BookingTravelerRef` you use the DOM methods which have a *NS* suffix, for example:

```
var element = xmlnode.getElementsByTagNameNS(nsURI, 'BookingTravelerRef');
console.log(element.getAttribute("Key")); // unprefixed attributes belong in no namespace
```

If you are using XPath, you create a function which resolves namespaces. SOAP responses typically have many namespaces, so you can deal with all of them in the same function. But if you are only interested in one, you can also inline the function:

```
function resolver(prefix) {
    if (prefix='common_v26_0') { return "your-namespace-uri"; }
    // else if ... other namespaces you might want to resolve
    else return null;
}
```

Then you can use it in XPath expressions:

```
xmlnode.evaluate("//common_v26_0:BookingTravelerRef/@Key", xmlnode, resolver, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

Finally you can *ignore* namespaces in XPath matching *all* elements and then filtering by their local names:

```
xmlnode.evaluate("//*[local-name()='BookingTravelerRef']/@Key", ...);
```

Comment: thanks helderdarocha, because the xml  will be converted to json   , we had wanted to remove prefix

Comment: To get the name of the tag without the prefix (you might use that to name the JSON properties), you just have to get the `local-name()` (instead of `name()`) and it will always be unprefixed.